# Fetching Two Joined Tables in SQL With Group By and Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read through every relevant question in here but couldn't figure out or modify the accepted answers to accomplish what I want.

I have two tables:

News: Id, Title, CategoryId
NewsCategory: Id, Title

I want to list all NewsCategories and include 10 rows of News belong to this category in the same Sql query.

I got this query working at the moment:

```
Select C.Id As CategoryId, C.Title As CategoryTitle, N.Id, N.Title
From NewsCategories C, News N
Where N.CategoryId In (C.Id)
Order By C.Id Desc
```

But couldn't figure out how to limit the amount of "News" returned without limiting NewsCategories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT C.Id AS CategoryId, C.Title AS CategoryTitle, N.Id, N.Title
From NewsCategories C
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 10 *
   FROM News 
   WHERE CategoryId = C.Id
) AS N
ORDER BY C.Id Desc
```

Depending on your requirements and the `News` table schema, you can perform an additional `ORDER BY` on the `OUTER APPLY` sub-query to, e.g., get the 10 latest news for each category or the 10 top news in alphabetical order, etc